# Only list direct (resolved) dependency paths with ldd, readelf or objdump

Tags: shared-library, elf

With `ldd` I can get a flat list of unique, fully resolved paths to all shared libraries that an executable depends on.

For a script where I'm bundling a binary, I'm copying over these shared libs. However, some shared libraries are blacklisted, meaning that I'm not copying them nor their subtree of dependencies (unless they are dependencies of non-blacklisted libs as well).

Is there a command that returns the resolved paths of the direct dependencies of an executable only? I know there is `readelf` and `objdump`, but they don't resolve the libraries like `ldd` does.

I realize there are some subtleties here, since I would have to manually keep track of `RPATH`s and forward them down the dependency tree.